# How should I declare that my method require any class?

Tags: c#, class, methods

When `Method` require any `string` we write that

```
void method(string str)
{
str="OK";
}
```

I have a `method` that require any `class`.
Little part of my `method`:

```
Void Post()
{
responsefromserver = new JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

`T`-must be any `class`.
But I don't know how should I declare that my `method` require any `class` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your method generic and add generic [parameter constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
void Post<T>()
   where T: class
{
    responsefromserver = new JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>(sr.ReadToEnd());
    // ...
}
```

You can parametrize it with any class:

```
Post<FooClass>(); // OK if FooClass is a class
Post<int>(); // fail, because integer is a value type
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it generic:

```
void Post<T>()
{
    responsefromserver = new JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

And then use it like:

```
 Post<YourClass>();
```

You can [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) your generic method if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You just inject dependency as a parameter or in your case - better to inject deserializer, and probably not on the `Post()` method level but on a class constructor level then reuse in `Post()`.